# Is there a API to obtain real-time forex data in seconds?

Tags: fx, market-data, trading, currency

I wanted to get sell, buy and recent trades of a currency in intervals of seconds but was only able to find APIs which offer a minimum interval of one minute (I checked Polygon and Alpha Advantage). Is there anything available to obtain real-time forex data in seconds, or is there nothing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few options available for real-time Forex data at intervals of seconds. However, these typically require a paid subscription or access to a premium account. Some options include:

- OANDA API: OANDA offers a REST API that provides access to streaming prices and historical data. Their premium accounts offer real-time data at intervals down to a few seconds. More information is available at https://developer.oanda.com/rest-live-v20/introduction/.
- ForexFeed API: ForexFeed offers a subscription-based service with access to real-time Forex data, including tick data. You can find more information at https://www.forexfeed.net/.
- TrueFX API: TrueFX offers a REST API that provides access to live streaming prices in real-time. You can find more information at https://www.truefx.com/.
- FXCM ForexConnect API: FXCM provides the ForexConnect API, which can be used to access real-time data at intervals down to a few seconds. More information is available at https://www.fxcm.com/markets/algos-and-apis/forexconnect-api/.

Answer (score 3):

One of the most frequently updated Forex APIs I have come across is [Tradermade Data API](https://tradermade.com/forex) Data updates sub-second with 100s of quotes per minute.